# Filter rows based on two columns together

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out rows based on two rows values. Most of the questions' solution that I see use the following approach:

`df.loc[(df['A'] != 'yes') & (df['B'] != 'no')]`

This filters the rows with a A and B different than one value, what I want to do is to filter rows where the columns have the values I am filtering, example:

```
Player | action | result
1          A        B
2          B        A
3          C        A
4          A        B
5          A        C
```

In this example I want to remove rows that have action `A` and result `B`. Using the example above it would remove actions equal to `A` and rows with result equal to `B`. I want to remove actions `A` that have result `B`.

**Output expected:**

```
  Player | action | result
    2          B        A
    3          C        A
    5          A        C
```

Probably I am making a lot of confusion here and this is straightforward. Anyhow, any help would be appreciated!

Regards

Comment: df[(df["action"] != "A" & df["result"] != "B")]

Comment: @yuRa that answer is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
pd.concat([df[(df['action'] == 'A') & (df['result'] != 'B')],df[(df['action'] != 'A')]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
df2[~((df2["action"]=='A') & (df2["result"]=='B'))]
```

Output of data frame will be as follows.

```
  Player action result
1   2    B    A
2   3    C    A
4   5    A    C
```